# Is it possible to disable the column on the left that is created by ALE?

Tags: plugin-ale

I installed the ALE plugin, and I really like the highlighting, though the sign column shown in the far left of this image is distracting to me and seems unnecessary given that errors and warnings are highlighted anyway.

[image: Sign column]

I've checked out out the ALE readme, but all I found relating to the sign column was this line `let g:ale_sign_column_always = 0`, which only seems to disable the column when there are no errors or warnings.

Is it possible to disable the sign column completely?

Comment: Does this work: `let g:ale_set_signs = 0`?

Comment: @Ralf Yes it does! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ralf mentions in the comments disabling ALE's sign column with

```
let g:ale_set_signs = 0
```

but you can also disable signs entirely with

```
set signcolumn=no
```

or have them in the number column with

```
set signcolumn=number
```